# How to compute this geometric progression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering how to compute this variant of geometric progression:
$$
\sum_{i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}, i \neq j} c^{i+j}?
$$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}, i \neq j} c^{i+j}
= \sum_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} \sum_{j \in \{1, \dots, n\}\backslash{i}} c^{i}c^{j}
\\= \sum_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} (\sum_{j \in \{1, \dots, n\}} c^{i}c^{j} - c^{i}c^{i})
\\= \sum_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} c^{i}(\sum_{j \in \{1, \dots, n\}} c^{j} - c^{i})
\\= (\sum_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} c^{i})^2-\sum_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} (c^2)^{i}
\\= (c\frac{c^n-1}{c-1})^2-c^2\frac{c^{2n}-1}{c^2-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

fix an $i$ then compute 
$$\sum _{i=1}^{n}e^i \left (\frac{e^{n+1}-e}{e-1}-e^{i} \right)$$
Now if you do the multiplication you will get two geometrics sums, which you can compute.

When you fix an $i$ the $j$ take every value expect the fixed $i$ in the numbers $(1,2, \dots ,n)$ so you get a geometric progression minus one term.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What if you allowed $i=j$ in the sum, and the subtracted those terms after?